# No logfile output when running script under screen, with console redirect (tee)

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have a python script that will write some general logging to the console. I've redirected this to a log file using the typical `python -u jbot.py | tee -a jbot.log`. This works fine, I get console output and logfile input. However, when attempting to run this under screen:

`screen python -u jbot.py | tee -a jbot.log`

I don't get any of the logging output to my file. Once I've disconnected from `screen`, does console output for that session get suppressed entirely, or is there a way I can still have logfile input from the stdout and stderr of my script?

I realize using a logging library would probably solve this (since I'm screening anyhow), but for now I want to stick with capturing console output (if possible) until I can properly integrate a logging module into my code.

Comment: That's a convoluted theory, but is there a chance that your script tries to assess the terminal's capabilities before writing to it, and decides that "screen" is not suitable? (The fact that you are piping to `tee` should make the writing process consider its output "not a terminal", which is why I call the theory convoluted.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
screen sh -c 'python -u jbot.py | tee -a jbot.log'
```

Basically, before you were piping the output of screen (not of your python script directly) to the log. Screen takes a command to execute as its argument, which it does itself not using a shell. So you need to explicitly make it run a shell.

Another option is to use screen's built-in output logging; see the `-L` option (also available inside screen via its UI).